# entity_privatemsg_message

Tags: 7, services, privatemsg, javascript

Working on a Android APP to read/reply private message (Drupal 7).

I am able to access all secure information for a user.

Services/Resources> works file. shows the entities

But I am facing some issues

I am trying to read the private messages of a user

1. When I am calling "entity_message" :

   `response :
   {
      "type": "private_message"
      "timestamp": "1466735100"
      "arguments": [0]
      "data": [0]
      "mid": "5"
      "uid": "1"
      "language": "en"
      "rdf_mapping": [0]
   }`

This is not message list for the requested user.

2. When I am calling "entity_privatemsg_message" :
   Response : "No entities found."

So this is also not messages we are looking for.